# # macro operator and std::string comparison in C++

Tags: c++, macros, stdstring

I have this bit of code that helps me convert enum to string and vice versa.

So I wrote a macro to make it look better and simpler:

```
#define SMART_REVERT_CASE(__CODE__, __STRING__)\
     if (__STRING__ == #__CODE__) return __CODE__
```

And then I call it this way:

```
enum EXAMPLE { HELLO, GOODBYE, ERROR };
EXAMPLE StringToExample(std::string const& input)
{
  SMART_REVERT_CASE(HELLO, input);
  SMART_REVERT_CASE(GOODBYE, input);
  return ERROR;

}
```

Unfortunately it does not compile (on VS 2008):

```
Error   1   error C2666: 'operator ==' : 5 overloads have similar conversions
```

Is there a way to give a hint to the compiler as to which operator== to use ?

Comment: Um, can you even call a macro with less arguments than it was defined with?

Comment: Using double underscores, or leading underscores followed by an upper-case letter is a **Bad Idea(tm)**. Those names are reserved for the implementation. *Especially* for relatively common names like `STRING` or `CODE`, you are just asking for name clashes with the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
__STRING__.compare( #__CODE__ )
```

BTW, using double underscores is a bad idea.

The C++11 draft n3290 defines the relevant `operator==` as:

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
  bool operator==(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
                  const charT* rhs) noexcept;
```

> *Requires:* rhs points to an array of at least traits::length(rhs) + 1 elements of charT.
>   *Returns:* lhs.compare(rhs) == 0.

so `compare` and `==` are the same thing here.

Comment: isn't compare a bit heavier in term of computing, since it returns a number instead of a bool, which means it reads the whole string ? Also do you have references as to why __ is wrong ?

Comment: That does not mean it reads the whole string. For GCC 4.5.3, `std::string operator==` is implemented with `return lhs.compare(rhs) == 0`. So there is no difference at all.

Comment: jules: Identifiers and ... anything really, beginning with double underscores or an underscore and a capitalized letter are implementation defined, so a compiler or Standard library implementation might have already used the names. Do not use them in user code. It *will* bite you back when you least expect it.

Comment: Leading `__` is used by internal [definitions by the compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html). And bools are ints. Anyways, if you worry about int <> bool etc you're probably optimizing prematurly.

Answer (score 1):

You can always cast to string and it should work

```
#define SMART_REVERT_CASE(__CODE__, __STRING__)\
     if (__STRING__ == std::string(#__CODE__)) return __CODE__
```

Note that I expect `__STRING__` to be a `std::string` here.

BTW what are the 5 overloads? There should be one specifically for `string` and `const char*`, which shouldn't need any conversions.

Comment: Same comment, isn't creating a temp string for it going to impact performances ?

Comment: @jules: Will you notice if it does?